# resetting the particular sudoku box in p5?

Tags: p5.js

I am trying to implement a Sudoku table in p5.js, I am able to implement a cell where I can write a number (1-9) down. But I cannot remove a number, i.e. if I write '1' first on a cell and write '2', it writes on top of it.

So, how can I remove the existing number and write a different one?

EDIT:

my code till now:

```
   //make a grid
function makegrid(rows, cols) {
  var regrid = new Array(rows);
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    regrid[i] = new Array(cols);
  }
  return regrid;
}

var numrec = [];
var rows = 9;
var grid = [];
var cols = 9;
var w = 50;
var input;

//show the boxes
function show(i, j) {
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  var x = w * this.i;
  var y = w * this.j;
  noFill();
  //input = createInput();
  //input.position(x+5,y+5,w);
  strokeWeight(1);
  rect(x + 5, y + 5, w, w); //just to see line clearly


}

//there must be a better way to do it but for now ---> here we go for separation
// of tables
function boldlines() {
  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(51);
  line(5, 5, 5, w * 9 + 5);
  line(w * 3 + 5, 5, w * 3 + 5, w * 9 + 5);
  line(w * 6 + 5, 5, w * 6 + 5, w * 9 + 5);
  line(5, w * 9 + 5, w * 9 + 5, w * 9 + 5);
  line(5, 5, w * 9 + 5, 5);
  line(w * 9 + 5, 5, w * 9 + 5, w * 9 + 5);
  line(5, w * 3 + 5, w * 9 + 5, w * 3 + 5);
  line(5, w * 6 + 5, w * 9 + 5, w * 6 + 5);

}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  grid = makegrid(rows, cols);
  numrec = makegrid(rows, cols);
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      numrec[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  boldlines();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      show(i, j);
      //console.log(mouseX,mouseY);
    }
  }
}


function numput(x, y, num) {
  //background(0);
  if (num === 0) {
    num = "";
  }
  textSize(30);
  //textAlign(CENTER);
  text(num, x + 30, y + 40);
}



function mousePressed() {
  var mx = mouseX;
  var my = mouseY;
  var i = floor((mx + 5) / w);
  var j = floor((my + 5) / w);
  if (i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < rows && j < cols) {
    //console.log(i, j);

    var num = numrec[i][j];
    if (num === 10) {
      num = 0;
    }
    numrec[i][j] = num + 1;
    numput(i * w, j * w, num);
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you storing the numbers?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to hide old number in that cell and retain the content of all the other cells. I hid the previous number by **drawing a rectangle** on top of it with the same dimensions of that of a cell and then updating the cell with new number.

```
function numput(x, y, num) {
  //background(0);
  if (num === 0) {
    num = "";
  }
  textSize(30);
  //textAlign(CENTER);

  //Newly added
  strokeWeight(0);
  fill(255,255,255);
  rect(x+4 , y+4 , w, w);
  boldlines();
  text(num, x + 30, y + 40);
}
```

I have done some changes in `function numput()` to achieve it.